# How to create an infinite loop

Tags: android, loops, timer, countdowntimer

Ok,I need to create an infinite loop on a countdown. My code is:

```
public void countdown() {
    if (x != null) {
        x.cancel();
    }

    x = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            showNotification();
        }
    };
    x.start();
}
```

x is just a static countdowntimer variable. The problem is that I tried many methods to make the above code work,I mean when the countdown ends,and it displays that notification,it should start again and so on....but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 17):

Hope this will help you.

```
public void countdown(){
    if (x != null) {
        x.cancel();
    }
    x = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
       public void onFinish() {
           showNotification();
            x.start();
        }
    };
 }
```

Answer (score 12):

For the record   CountDownTimer(**long** millisInFuture, **long** countDownInterval)

```
  // A not so infinite but close to infinte interval for each second
  CountDownTimer cdt=new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) { .... }
```

Where Long.MAX_VALUE =  9223372036854775807  miliseconds or around 292 million of years (seconds more or less)

Its not infinite but its incredibly long.

Answer (score 6):

is to restart your timer when his has finished :)
 like this :

```
   x = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                showNotification();
                start();// here, when your CountDownTimer has finished , we start it again :)
            }
        };
        x.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

### Simple way to create an infinite loop:

**Every one secod call method**

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) 
   {
        public void onTick(long l) {}
        public void onFinish() 
        {
          //Code hear
          start();
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a regular Timer?  It will repeat on a specified interval until you call cancel(), something like:

```
public void countdown() { 
    if (x != null) {
        x.cancel();
    }

    x = new Timer("timerName");
    x.schedule(_timerTask, 0, 20000);
}

private static final TimerTask _timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showNotification();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a while loop:
`while (true) {

// do stuff

}`
When it has done "the stuff" it wil start again, infinite!

Comment: this will not restart the CountDownTimer infinitly , but it will instanciate and start a loot of Timers infinitly , which is not what the guy Want :)

Comment: CPU Usages lot with this method and need to use asynctask

Answer (score 1):

to keep your timer working just put

```
<countdowntime>.start();
```

in the `onfinish` block

Comment: this.start();;;

Comment: or just `start();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have implemented an indefinite timer that takes multiple listeners and calls them simultaneously on a specific interval.

```java
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class InfiniteCounter extends CountDownTimer {

    private static final int MAX_LISTENERS = 100;

    private static InfiniteCounter timer;
    private static InfiniteCounterListener[] listenerList = new InfiniteCounterListener[MAX_LISTENERS];

    private InfiniteCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    //Milliseconds Intervals in which the counter should call its listeners 
    public static InfiniteCounter initInstance(int intervalMillis) {
        removeAllListeners();
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new InfiniteCounter(60 * 60 * 1000, intervalMillis);
            timer.start();
        }
        return timer;
    }

    public static void attachListener(InfiniteCounterListener listener) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LISTENERS; i++) {
            if (listenerList[i] == null) {
                listenerList[i] = listener;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void removeListener(InfiniteCounterListener listener) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LISTENERS; i++) {
            if (listenerList[i] == listener) {
                listenerList[i] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void removeAllListeners() {
        Arrays.fill(listenerList, null);
    }

    public static void stopTimer() {
        removeAllListeners();
        if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LISTENERS; i++) {
            if (listenerList[i] != null) listenerList[i].onTick();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public interface InfiniteCounterListener {
        void onTick();
    }
}
```

Just Attach listeners to this class and with single timer, it can call multiple listeners -- which makes is very performance optimised.