# How to create auto counting code for Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make an option in my application that if you click a button a counter will start and it will count (like 0++) and show the number until user stops it, so far I have this non working code

```
if (v == btn3) {
        counter = 0;

        scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                while (counter < 1000 ) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    counter++;
                }

            }

        }).start();
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }
```

Currently when i press the button, the text field only turns red and is set to 0, but I can't make it count

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion setText method is outside loop. It could update text view after loop ends. Move it somewhere inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a class called [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) which provides some useful functionality. In particular it provides an onTick() method with which you could update your text field at a desired interval.

You would need to create a CountDownTimer to count indefinitely, which you can do by restarting the timer in its onFinish() method, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278041/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop) question. But if you set the CountDownTimer for long enough, you probably would never need to restart it.

Something like this...

```
new CountDownTimer(<REALLY_BIG_NUMBER>, 500) {

 int counter = 0;

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     scoreText.setText(counter++);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     start();
 }
 }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as per your needs

```
if (v == btn3) {
    counter = 0;

    scoreText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            while (counter < 1000 ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                 }
                }); 
                counter++;
            }

        }

    }).start();
}
```

Comment: It is working thank you, but what was the problem with mine

Comment: It is prohibited to update the ui from child threads, since they cannot be monitored. This is why main thread is also called the ui thread. Also you were updating the textview from outside the loop, so it just showed 0, the initial value.